# 5 Monitors including the laptop screen - XPS 15 7590

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Laptop: Dell XPS 15 7590 32Gb Ram, Core i7 2.6ghz (6 cores)
GPU 0: Intel UHD Graphics 630
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650

Laptop Screen: 3840 x 2160
Monitors: 2 BENQ 27" PD2700 - Resolution 2560 x 1440
Monitors: 2 older BENGQ 24" - Resolution 1920 x 1080

Docking Station: Dell TB16 / K16

Cable Matters 3-Port USB-C to MST Multi-Monitor Hub

I'm on Windows 10 Pro.

I am able to connect my 2 PD2700 to the laptop through the docking station and have the laptop screen up. So I am able to get 3 screens working. I don't need the cable matters hub to make that work. I believe my monitors support Displayport 1.4 but I'm not sure that I can make MST work with them because they don't have a Displayport out.

Today I tried to connect one of the older 24" Benq monitors but when I connected the third monitor I lost the laptop screen. Even if I reduced the resolution on all monitors to 1280 x 768.

Is it possible to get the 4 monitors and the laptop screen connected with this equipment? If not but it is possible with different equipment, what equipment do I need?

Thanks

Comment: You'd do better to ask Dell to be certain, but laptops that can take more than 2 external monitors are few & far between. Usually you're in danger of frying the mobo if you can even  get a third display running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA doesn't specify the maximum number of monitors, but
[Gigabyte specifications for GTX 1650](https://www.cnet.com/products/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-1650-oc-4g-graphics-card-gf-gtx-1650-4-gb/)
does say "Max Monitors Supported : 3".

So it seems that the GTX 1650 has only three data-paths and no more,
supporting up to three monitors.

Using DisplayPort port you can chain more monitors, but your monitors are unsuitable. In any case, daisy chaining will not avoid the limitation
of 3 monitors.

One solution is to replace the GTX 1650 with a better card
(which might not be physically possible).
Then the combined ports of the computer and dock (twice DisplayPort+VGA+HDMI)
might be enough.

As Tetsujin has commented above, the hardware of the laptop itself might not
be able to take the load.

Your two video cards together can support 5 monitors, but I don't think
that the laptop's physical design allows separating the two,
as usually one feeds through the other.

The only real solution I can see with your current hardware is to get
larger but fewer monitors that will give you enough total desktop space.
As a general note, a desktop would be more suitable for 5 monitors than a laptop.

Comment: So, if I understand you, it sounds like you're saying that purchasing monitors that have a display port out, won't allow me to daisy chain, and won't enable this functionality either, with the current laptop? I would think that the specified limit there is because it only has 3 connectors. 2 hdmi and 1 display port.

Comment: I was talking about the current hardware. Yes, with the right monitors you can daisy chain, although too many monitors on one daisy chain might work poorly, so testing is required. But daisy chaining will not avoid the limitation of 3 monitors.